# How to Limit the size of the option name in the select box?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, drop-down-menu

I am retrieving the options of the select box from the database. I want to limit the width of the option value in the drop down box.

Eg:   The value in the data base is "ELEPHANT GROUP"
      In my drop down if i need only 8 characters long.
      The value to be displayed in the dropdown box is "ELEPHANT"

I want my option values to be limited to a particular size. Can any one help me in resolving this issue.?

Brief Info:

My developer has a dynamic list box on one of his forms. ie: The Administrative user can create options which display in a Select Box for the General User to choose from. Our intention was for the Admin User to create options of about 50 characters max, but our business requirements do not allow us to restrict the size of the Option Name the Admin User creates.
This leaves us open to the possibility of a SelectBox that is hundreds of characters wide, throwing all table formatting out the window and causing the screen to scroll horizontally.
We've been arguing about this endlessly for days now, and apparently CANNOT limit the character input for the Option Name. Is there any way to manipulate the display of the Select Box to prevent it from exceeding a certain number of characters wide but still show very long Option Names?

Hope now u have got my problem exactly.. Please help me in resolving it.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a [`substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to get the 8 firsts characters to show

Comment: I tried to use substring function. i can able to use it for normal string but im not able to use it for the options of the dropdown. Can you just give me some example  please.?

Comment: in the code when you show the select when compose the options `<option value="xx">OPTION_TEXT_VERY_LARGE</option>` you can do `<option value="xx">OPTION_TEXT_VERY_LARGE.substring(0, NUM_CHARS_WANT_TO_SHOW);</option>`

Comment: I tried with this above format. Its not working. It is displaying blank values in the options.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<select id = "mysel" onchange = "show()">
<option value = 0>Select one ....</option>
<option value = "January">January</option>
<option value = "February">February</option>
<option value = "March">March</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type = "text" id = "month" size = "1" readonly>

<script type = "text/javascript">

function show() {
var val = document.getElementById("mysel").value;
val = val.substring(0,3);
alert (val);
document.getElementById("month").value = val;
}

</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

/*By using the substring u can do it.Else you can specify the width of a box with style with the newer browsers that support CSS. The only problem is, you can not see the whole word. It cuts it off.

hope that helps you out*/

Comment: This is not the functionality i have asked for.